# Properly organizing Kruskal-Wallis for two different analyses

Tags: multiple-comparisons, ordinal-data, kruskal-wallis-test

I have the following data:

Seven substances (hereafter S1–S7);
Inside each substance, I have 30 scores (10 for each of three layers (let's call them A, B, and C)). The scores (1–5) are also ordinal. An example:

**S1**
A - 10;
B - 10;
C - 10;

**S2**
A - 10;
B - 10;
C - 10;

And so on.

So, I have two questions:

1. Compare the effect of each S1-S7 on the scores;
2. Compare the effect of each S1-S7 on the scores while considering the A, B, C layers.

What's the correct way of organizing the data for this? For question (1) I think simply doing a scores ~ substances is enough, but how can I add the layers idea in (2)? Is it a simple two-way?